# Is it possible to play M3U8 playlist inside a M3U8 playlist?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, m3u8, http-live-streaming

I mean something like tis:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXTINF:10,
video0.ts
#EXTINF:8,
video1.ts
#EXTINF:10,
video2.ts
#EXTPLAYLIST //HERE COMES A PLAYLIST
anotherplaylist.m3u8
```

I know about 'variant' playlist but I don't think that it's the thing I look for.

Thank you

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I want to create a master playlist which contains a few media which are also HTTP live streams.

Comment: How do you wish to use this master playlist? What are your goals? The reason I ask is that I have the feeling you are asking the wrong question here - if you can describe the full scenario, I might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Technically this is possible by parsing the original m3u8 and then recreating the url using the relative path of the m3u8 you want. What you need is to write a script to extract out the m3u8 from the original m3u8 and then use that info to provide the m3u8 path to your player. Hope that answers the question. Since this appears to be quite custom I am not sure you will find a predefined script out there doing this but this should not be very hard.

Comment: Do you mean getting both m3u8's segments and merging them in another m3u8?

Comment: @scaryguy, not sure what you mean there. Do you want to play the m3u8 that is inside? Or do you want to play the m3u8 that is containing this m3u8 and want to give another m3u8 in it and not all segments. I think i got confused there. If you want to give m3u8 instead of ts files then I am not sure that is possible. So far I have been answering assuming you want to play only the m3u8 inside another m3u8. But here it appears you want to play the outer m3u8 and put more m3u8's inside it. I am not sure that is possible directly unless the HLS rfc allows it.

Comment: Is it possible to make HLS formatted videos available to user offline on there browsers?

Is it possible to store HLS video in users browser (in Indexed db etc) and then play directly from there (At least for a short term period)?